# Mandatory Fields in Userform

Tags: vba

I have a userform with three fields (textbox, command box and list box) and I am trying to make it so that when you press OK, if all the fields aren't completed you will get an error message. So all three fields should be populated.

I have tried the code below, which initially works for the text box (but if you enter a value and then delete it the message won't pop up again) but doesn't work for the command box.

If someone could help with this, it would be greatly appreciated:

```
If CR_Slide.CRNumber.Text = " " Then
MsgBox "Complete all fields"
End If

If CR_Slide.Severity.SelText = " " Then
MsgBox "Complete all fields"
End If
```

Comment: Why  " " instead of ""? A string containing a single space isn't an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing if the input is a string consisting of a single space. The fact that you said it "works the first time for the text box" suggests that sometimes you do have non-empty white space. You could take the text and first run it through the function `trim` which will trim any all-white space string down to the empty string, which is the unique string of length 0. Something like:

```
If Len(Trim(CR_Slide.CRNumber.Value)) = 0 Then
MsgBox "Complete all fields"
End If

If Len(Trim(CR_Slide.Severity.Value)) = 0 Then
MsgBox "Complete all fields"
End If
```

should work. (I switched from `Text` to `Value` since it is standard to get user input via the `Value` property of the control).

Comment: I completely missed that the OP was searching for a space. I might add though it's still a good idea to end the code after the message box otherwise if you have say 5 fields without entries that you test, you will get 5 messages.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to end the procedure when the box has popped up:

```
If CR_Slide.CRNumber.Text = " " Then
MsgBox "Complete all fields"
End
End If

If CR_Slide.Severity.SelText = " " Then
MsgBox "Complete all fields"
End
End If
```

Or maybe `Exit Sub` instead of `End`