# How come IsNull(), IsEmpty(), Application.WorksheetFunction.Istext() does not work on combo boxes?

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have tried the several variations below and even if I do not select or type anything in the combo box, the MsgBox never runs.

Variation 1:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If IsNull(cmbPaidTo.Text) = True Then
    MsgBox "Payee cannot be empty."
End If

Unload Me
UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Variation 2:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If IsNull(cmbPaidTo) = True Then
    MsgBox "Payee cannot be empty."
End If

Unload Me
UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Variation 3:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If IsEmpty(cmbPaidTo.Text) = True Then
    MsgBox "Payee cannot be empty."
End If

Unload Me
UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Variation 4:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If IsEmpty(cmbPaidTo) = True Then
    MsgBox "Payee cannot be empty."
End If

Unload Me
UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Variation 5:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(cbxPaidTo.Text) = False Then
    MsgBox "Payee cannot be empty."
End If

Unload Me
UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Variation 6:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(cbxPaidTo) = False Then
    MsgBox "Payee cannot be empty."
End If

Unload Me
UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

The combo box should never be empty when the form is submitted, but I cannot understand why I can't get it to work.

This is what my UserForm looks like:
[image: UserForm]

The combobox i'm pointing at is the one without a text label.

Comment: Possible duplicate, check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085816/mandatory-fields-in-userform).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `IsNull()` should be used only for Access queries. The value of the input box cannot be `Null`.
- `IsEmpty()` - Returns a Boolean value indicating whether avariable has been initialized. Mainly used for ranges and cells in Excel. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/isempty-function). The `cbxPaidTo.Text` cannot be Empty, because it is an initialized object.
- `.IsText()` - here the things are a bit different. Even the empty string `""` is still considered text. And whenever you have nothing in your form, it is returning an empty string. Check this:

---

```
Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.IsText("")
End Sub
```

---

A possible solution is to check the size of the input [(as mentioned here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50561592/5448626) , after Trimming. Like this:

```
If Trim(Len(cmbPaidTo) Then
```

Comment: Thanks this works! With the little addition of the trim function which is also great when needed

Comment: @MarcSantos - super :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
If len(cmbPaidTo) = 0 Then
```

The value of the combobox will always be a string ""